# Join figure and table on the same page

Tags: tables, floats

I have a figure and and a table and I want to make sure they both appear on the same page. I want both objects to keep their natural numbering and captioning: The Figure should be captioned `Figure 1.2.3: Text` and the  Table should be captioned `Table 1.2.3: Text 2`. Currently, I specified `[pt]` as placement for both, but this (of course) does not what I need.

I know the following two solutions:

1. Use `\subfloat`
2. Use a single `figure` and put both, the table and the figure in this figure and using `\caption` twice.

Both solution do not lead to the captioning I need: The first solution generates a single figure and the second one creates two figures. I need a Figure and a Table for the captions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I gather that the `figure` should be at the very top of a page, to be followed immediately by the `table` environment. (Moreover, I'm taking for granted that the two environments will actually fit on a single page, right?)

You could achieve these objectives by loading the `afterpage` package and "encasing" the `figure` and `table` environments in an `\afterpage{...}` statement, as is shown in the following code fragment:

```
\afterpage{%    % defer execution until the next page break occurs anyway
   \begin{figure}[t!] % not "pt"
      \centering
      % remaining contents of figure environment
   \end{figure}
   \begin{table}[h!] % not t or b or p
      \centering
      % remaining contents of table environment
   \end{table}
} % end of argument of `\afterpage` command
```

I'm further assuming that there are no deferred figure and/or table environments already waiting to be typeset. If that were the case, you should issue a `\clearpage` instruction as the very first item in the argument of the `\afterpage` command. (Even if there are no accumulated deferred floats to take care of, there's no harm done by issuing a `\clearpage` instruction anyway at the start of the `\afterpage` material; it would simply be ignored by TeX.)

In addition, if the figure and table environments combined take up most of the page (say, more than 75% of the page), you may also want to issue a second `\clearpage` instruction, following the end of the `table` environment. This will tell LaTeX that you want to have just those two floats on the page in question.

Comment: Works like it should. Additionally this works together with the `\subfloat` command in the figures where the other two solutions fail.

Comment: Why the downvote today, on an answer posted nearly five years ago? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [capt-of](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) package to put individual captions for the table and the figure with or without using the usual floating environments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

A non-floating version works\dots
\begin{center}
  \captionof{table}{Caption of the first table}\label{tab:tableone}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  ... & ... \\
  \end{tabular}
  \\[\floatsep]
  \rule{4cm}{2cm} % \includegraphics{yourpicture}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption of the first figure}\label{fig:figureone}
\end{center}

\dots as well as a floating example.
\begin{figure}[bp]
  \centering
  \captionof{table}{Caption of the second table}\label{tab:tabletwo}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  ... & ... \\
  \end{tabular}
  \\[\floatsep]
  \rule{4cm}{2cm} % \includegraphics{yourpicture}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption of the second figure}\label{fig:figuretwo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: extended the example to show a floating environment, too.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) package with the help of the underlying [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe} %<- For dummy image
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{andtable}{#1˜#2 \& \tablename˜\thetable}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\listoffigures


\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
\label{fig:fig1}
\caption{important image}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
a &b\\c&d
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:table1}
\caption{important result}
\end{subfigure}
\captionlistentry[table]{important result}
\captionsetup{labelformat=andtable}
\caption[important image]{typeset together}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]