# Get a table and figure on the same page with captions & labels

Tags: tables, floats, cross-referencing, captions

Here's what I'm looking for: I need a table and a figure to stay on the same page, while keeping captions & labels fully functional. Both the table and the figure need their own caption and their own label.

The `\afterpage` command almost made it work (which I found in [Join figure and table on the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/join-figure-and-table-on-the-same-page)), but the labels to reference them in the text don't work anymore (no matter where I place my `\afterpage` environment. The table & figure together make up almost a full page, if that helps.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  Please take a look at these two questions (duplicate?):  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To guarantee that they will remain together, use either one `minipage` (if the object doesn't have to be treated as floating) or just *one* floating environment for both the figure and the table; the right type of caption can then be obtained, in both cases, using `\captionof` from the [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) (or [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption)) packages; the example below shows both possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{examplefigure}
\captionof{figure}{Example figure caption (non-floating)}
\label{fig:examplenf}

\captionof{table}{Example Table (non-floating)}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
column1a & column2a \\
column1b & column2b \\
column1c & column2c \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:examplenf}
\end{minipage} 

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{examplefigure}
\caption{Example figure caption (floating)}
\label{fig:examplefl}

\captionof{table}{Example Table (floating)}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
column1a & column2a \\
column1b & column2b \\
column1c & column2c \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:examplefl}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This did the trick (floating one), thanks! I turned it around though, and just used captof for the figure and put it all in a table environment (made a little more sense content-wise to get the table above the figure but I forgot to say that).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting one float on the top by using the `[t]` option and another one on the bottom `[b]`, as shown in the example:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{examplefigure}
   \caption{Example figure caption}
   \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[b]
    \caption{Example Table}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    hello & world\\
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:example}
\end{table}
```

Or, as stated in these two questions:

[Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

[Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)

You can force them to be where you want them by using the `float` package along with the `[H]` option.  However, this is not advisable.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work..

Comment: I can confirm that this will not always work even though I'd expect it to (that's what started my search actually).

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting the captions to work with the solution previously posted by @Gonzalo Medina. Specifically, my captions were in the form:

```
\caption[short caption for table of contents]{long caption underneath figure}
```

The `\captionof` command doesn't take a short caption. When using `\caption` instead, my table was captioned as a figure.

I was able to solve the problem with an alternative solution, using the `afterpage` package, as:

```
\usepackage{afterpage}

\afterpage{
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption[short caption]{long caption}
  \label{table_label}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
       % table material
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figure_file}
    \caption[short caption]{long caption}
    \label{figure_label}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
} % <-- last curly brace ends \afterpage environment
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table environment with its `\caption{Caption of the figure}` and then, underneath, put your table with a `\captionof{table}{Caption of the table}` command to get the table.