# Place table and figures into same float with subcaption package

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption

I want to have a float which covers an entire page, but with a table and two figures inside. From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111121 I figured (no pun indented) I need to write (using the caption and the subcaption package)

```
\documentclass[english]{llncs}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\RequirePackage[allowlitunits]{siunitx}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}{}{\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}}
\makeatother
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period,font={small}}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={bf},name={Table},labelsep=period,font={small}}
\RequirePackage[labelfont={bf},name={Fig.},labelsep=period,font={small}]{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{Z}{S[
    table-format=1.3,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=3]}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering

    \captionof{table}{My table text}
    \label{tab:nmi}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    this & and & that
    \end{tabular}\vspace{3mm}

    
    \includegraphics [width=\textwidth] {fig1.pdf}
    \captionof{figure}{My fig 1 text}
    \label{fig:nmi_alldatasets}
    
    \includegraphics [width=\textwidth] {fig2.pdf}
    \caption{figure}{My fig 2 text}
    \label{fig:nmi1_perdataset}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(Please find the class at ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip)

But now I get the warnings

> The caption type was already set to 'figure'(caption) on input line 27
>
> The caption type was already set to 'table'(caption) on input line 36

Otherwise this is exactly what I want. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The springer class has its own caption handling. Define a `\captionof` which do not needs a package:

```
\documentclass[english]{llncs}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\captionof#1{%
    \begingroup
    \def\@captype{#1}%
    \@ifnextchar[\captionof@i{\captionof@ii}}
\def\captionof@i[#1]#2{\caption[#1]{#2}\endgroup}
\def\captionof@ii#1{\caption{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionof{table}{My table text}\label{tab:nmi}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    this & and & that
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1.pdf}
\caption{My fig 1 text}\label{fig:nmi_alldatasets}

\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2.pdf}
\caption{My fig 2 text}\label{fig:nmil_perdatasets}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It can be a simple definition if you use inside a figure or table environment *always* `\captionof` and not a mix of `\caption` and `\captionof`