# Creating a figure, with subfigures on the same page as a table

Tags: floats

I have a figure with multiple subfigures and a related table that I want to appear directly below them.

I have been experimenting with code from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111110/get-a-table-and-figure-on-the-same-page-with-captions-labels) but its not for figures with subfigures and I so far can't get a solution to work.

Any ideas of how to do this?

(an attempt)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\renewcommand\thesubtable{(\alph{subtable})}
```

`\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{figure}
        %\centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{LwT2_3d_statespace1.png}
            %\label{LwT1AssPhase}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{LwT2_3d_statespace2.png}
            %\label{LwT1DissPhase}
        \end{subfigure} 
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{LwT2_3d_statespace3.png}
            %\label{LwT1AssPhase}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{LwT2_3d_statespace4.png}
            %\label{LwT1DissPhase}
        \end{subfigure} \caption[Visualisations of a solution trajectory for the Langmuir two concentration model in the association phase]{Visualisations of a solution trajectory for the Langmuir two concentration model in the association phase (cyan) alongside nullcline-planes $x_1$ in blue, $x_2$ in red, $C$ in green}
    \label{LwT2PhasePort}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}
    { | c | c | c | c | c | c |c |c |c |  }
    \hline
    Parameter                      &$k_{a1}$              & $k_{a2}$       & $k_{d1}$& $k_{d2}$&     $R$            & $C_T$ & $k_m$                                         & $h$ \\%\hline
                                   &M$^{-1}$s$^{-1}$      &M$^{-1}$s$^{-1}$&s$^{-1}$ &s$^{-1}$ & pg nm$^{-2}$       & nM    &  pgnm$^{-2}$ M$^{-1}$s$^{-1}$                  &pgnm$^{-2}$ M$^{-1}$ \\\hline%\hline
    Value                          &6E-4                  &5E-4            &7E-3     &1E-2     & 500                &  100  & 10$^{-4}$                                     & 10$^{-6}$  \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Values taken by parameters in Fig. \ref{LwT2PhasePort} and  \ref{LwT2dPhasePort}}%add key
    \label{tab:LwTsols}
    \end{table}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}`

``

Comment: please, show us what you try so far. in form of small but complete document. without seeing it we can't help you.

Comment: just added. I thought my code was too wrong to be a useful starting point

Comment: Note that figures and tables are primarily floats and secondarily have captions.  Subfigures are just minipages with different captions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale factors were causing weird problems, so replaced with with width specifications.  Note: I used two different approaches w.r.t. positioning the "subfigures" for demonstration purposes.

I took rather extreme liberties trying to get the tabular to fit the page.  I'm not happy with the default footnote marks (minipages), but am too tired to figure out how to change them right now.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\renewcommand\thesubtable{(\alph{subtable})}
\usepackage{array}% for \extrasrrowheight
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{LwT2_3d_statespace1.png}
            \captionof{subfigure}{}
            \label{LwT1AssPhase}
        \end{minipage}\hfil
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{LwT2_3d_statespace2.png}
            \captionof{subfigure}{}
            \label{LwT1DissPhase}
        \end{minipage}

        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{LwT2_3d_statespace3.png}
            \captionof{subfigure}{}
            \label{LwT1AssPhase}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{LwT2_3d_statespace4.png}
            \captionof{subfigure}{}
            \label{LwT1DissPhase}
        \end{minipage}

        \captionof{figure}[Visualisations of a solution trajectory for the Langmuir two concentration model in the association phase]%
          {Visualisations of a solution trajectory for the Langmuir two concentration model in the association phase (cyan) alongside nullcline-planes $x_1$ in blue, $x_2$ in red, $C$ in green}
    \label{LwT2PhasePort}

    \vspace{\floatsep}% standard interfloat separation
    \captionof{table}{Values taken by parameters in Fig. \ref{LwT2PhasePort} and  \ref{LwT2dPhasePort}}%add key
    \label{tab:LwTsols}
    \small
    \sisetup{exponent-product = \cdot}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}% 9*{c|}
    \hline
    Parameter  &$k_{a1}$ & $k_{a2}$ & $k_{d1}$ & $k_{d2}$ & $R$ & $C_T$ & $k_m$ & $h$ \\%\hline
       & \si{M^{-1} s^{-1}} & \si{M^{-1}s^{-1}} & \si{s^{-1}} & \si{s^{-1}} & \footnote{\si{pg nm^{-2}}} & nM
           & \footnote{\si{pgnm^{-2}M^{-1}s^{-1}}}
           & \footnote{\si{pgnm^{-2}M^{-1}}} \\
    \hline%\hline
    Value & \num{6E-4} & \num{5E-4} & \num{7E-3} & \num{1E-2} & 500 & 100 & \num{E-4} & \num{E-6}  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried to compile this with my document and got this error https://snag.gy/KPtDjO.jpg - it looks like its caused by the siunitx sty file;. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: the version of siunitx is the generic one that miktex package manager downloaded, I can't seem to find any other version.

Comment: As this seemed like a big question I moved it to its on question page so it would be more visible https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450971/undefined-control-sequence-in-the-siunitx-sty-file thanks for your help

Comment: It looks like it will be hard for me to get siunitx working on my computer; is there any way of doing this without it?

Comment: Sure, just use your original tabular.  It was just that your table cried out "Use siunitx!" and I couldn't resist.

Comment: Thanks so much; I'm now using this method. I've noticed that this method seems to affect the text in other ways than a large figure, or a set of figures organically placed together would. Here is one example https://snag.gy/l8h1dB.jpg rather than taking up a whole page a single line of text is placed on the bottom. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: If you want it on a separate page, just replace the outer minipage with a figure or table [p].  You can then lose the \noindent.

Comment: is there a way of doing it so that it doesn't change the number of the next figure or table?

Comment: great; worked it out! :)