# \label is Undefined when used in \afterpage?

Tags: floats, errors, labels, afterpage

I am trying to force a figure and an image to show up on the same page back to back. I read the solution of using the `\afterpage` which works great. Except now the `\label` is undefined and I cannot refer to them!

What I have so far:

```
\afterpage{
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{PATH_TO_IMAGE}
        \caption{Some Caption For My Image}
        \label{myFigure}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Some Caption For My Table}
        \label{myTable}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.09]{PATH_TO_TABLE}
    \end{table}
}
```

Then I refer to these normally, using `\ref{myFigure}` or `\ref{myTable}`. But the compiler says undefined references, and the PDF shows `??`. If I remove the `/afterpage`, then the reference works just fine.

Why?

**EDIT**

This is for my dissertation paper at my university. The following [template](https://github.com/briandealwis/ubcdiss) is provided by the university to be used.

The path to the main `.tex` file is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/briandealwis/ubcdiss/master/diss.tex)

Comment: Can you please add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Your configuration seems to be causing the problem as I just threw together a quick MWE and the links were fine, both with and without hyperref (and `\autoref`). Please post a MWE!

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for the response. This is a dissertation paper and I am using the template provided by the university. I provided the links above. Is this enough as a MWE?

Comment: If you wish to keep things together on the same page back-to-back, you could include them in the same float. Use `\captionof` (from [`capt-of`](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) or [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)) to provide the correct `\caption` for the alternative float.

Comment: Heiko's answered the question although it's hard to see why you need afterpage here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I need the `\afterpage` cause I need to force the figure and table to be on the same page.

Comment: @user834045 `afterpage` is a highly invasive package that does _lots_ of stuff and more or less none of that is at all relevant to keeping floats on the same page. In what way are you using it? I wrote the thing and I can't guess:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for the response. I Googled the question on how to force an image and a table to be on the same page, and I got this page: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/join-figure-and-table-on-the-same-page where it was suggested to use \afterpage.

Comment: @user834045 urg I wouldn't do that, although I suppose it sort of works (although it doesn't guarantee they end up on the same page it makes it a bit more likely) I'd do what werner suggests in the comment above, which is guaranteed to keep things together

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, will this work with figure and tables? And each will have a different label/numbering?

Comment: @user834045 yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a timing problem between `afterpage` and the end of `\include`. After the `.tex` file is read, `\include` calls `\clearpage`, which is redefined by `afterpage`. First the page is output, then the stuff inside `\afterpage` is executed. The stuff are float objects, thus they are not yet set, waiting for the next call of the output routine. In the meantime, `\include` closes the `.aux` file for the included file and finishes its job. Then, when the floats are output, the labels are written to the *old* `.aux` file for the former included file, but this `.aux` file is closed, thus the labels are written to the `.log` file and console instead. In the next LaTeX run the labels remain unknown.

**Workaround:** An explicit `\clearpage` at the end of the included file helps. Then this `\clearpage` triggers the `afterpage` hook to execute, and the `\clearpage` at the end of `\include` will trigger the floats to output *before* the `.aux` file gets closed.